# How do I install an application for just one user?

Tags: install, permission

How do I install an application for just one user, without using administrative permissions or affecting any other users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put the application in the home of the user. You could create folders like this for every user:

```
/Users/<username1>/Applications
/Users/<username2>/Applications
```

and put the application(s) there.

Comment: The nice thing about mac os x is apps can typically run from anywhere.  It's best for sanity to put them in the application folders (system and or user) but not strictly required.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, since I have the same question - but I don't have a /User/(myusername) only /User/someotheruser/, and /User is owned by root!

Comment: When I trie to do this it creates a shortcut. Is there a way to move it completely (dropbox)?